# Decode mediaRecorder audio file in Python

Tags: python, typescript, audio, openai-whisper

I am sending 2s audio files from my typescript frontend to my python Flask backend, where I need to access to this files and turn them to mp3 files for the whisper model.

My funtion to send the data is:

```
function sendData() {


//This line checks if the recording flag is false. If so, it returns from the function, because there is no data to send.
  if (!recording) {
      return;
  }

  //This line creates a Blob object from the chunks array, which contains the audio data that has been recorded 
  //since the last time data was sent to the backend.
  let blob = new Blob(chunks, {type : 'audio/webm;codecs=opus'});
  console.log(blob)
  //This line creates a new FormData object and appends the Blob object to it. 
  //The append() method takes three arguments: the field name ("audio"), the Blob object, and the filename ("recording.webm").
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("file", blob, "recording.webm");
  for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
    console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]); 
  }
  //This line sends the FormData object to the /api/increment endpoint of the backend server using the fetch() method. 
  //The fetch() method returns a promise that resolves to the server's response. 
  //In this case, we're assuming that the server will respond with JSON data containing a position property.
  //The response is parsed as JSON using the json() method and the resulting position value is assigned to the position variable. 
  //Finally, the updateResult() function is called to highlight the word at the specified position on the webpage.
  fetch("http://localhost:5050/audio", {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData
  }).then(response => {
      return response.json();
  }).then(data => {
      position = data.position;
      updateResult();
  });
  chunks = [];
}
```

And my code in Python:

```
@app.route('/audio', methods=['POST', 'OPTIONS'])
def handle_key_data():
    if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
        response = app.response_class(
            status=200,
            mimetype='application/json'
        )
    else:
        data = request.files['file'].stream
        print(data)
        response = app.response_class(
            status=200,
            mimetype='application/json'
        )
        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'http://localhost:5173'
         
        
    return response
```

Which prints: "<class 'tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile'>" and I do not find the way to deal with this type of variable

Could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `request.files['file'].save()` method then use a library like `pydub` to convert the saved `.webm` file to `.mp3`.

first we install `pydub` `pip install pydub` and ffmpeg here https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html

Then we update our Flask function:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

@app.route('/audio', methods=['POST', 'OPTIONS'])
def handle_key_data():
    if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
        response = app.response_class(
            status=200,
            mimetype='application/json'
        )
    else:
        input_file = request.files['file']
        input_file_path = 'recording.webm'
        input_file.save(input_file_path)

        webm_audio = AudioSegment.from_file(input_file_path, format="webm")
        output_file_path = 'recording.mp3'
        webm_audio.export(output_file_path, format="mp3")

        response = app.response_class(
            status=200,
            mimetype='application/json'
        )
        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'http://localhost:5173'

    return response
```